# can I avoid auto-rewarding of a bounty?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bounty

I posted a large bounty and a couple of users posted incomplete responses that did not answer the stated question.  The bounty expired.  I accept that the points are gone because I gambled them and lost the wager.  But I received a message stating that the bounty will be auto-awarded if I do not award it myself in 23 hours.

To me, this seems like outright theft.  I am eager to award the entire bounty to someone who actually answers what I think is a very straightforward question requiring a modest amount of time that is less than the amount of time that the user might have to invest in other methods by which a user might accrue a similar amount of points.  But if the question is not answered at the standard defined by the bounty, then the bounty should not be rewarded.

**What alternatives do I have to avoid auto-rewarding the bounty?**

Comment: "I want to be grateful to the respondents" - but you'd rather have the reputation completely destroyed rather than given out to them. From reading the question, it looks like both (one in particular) spent a *large amount of time* trying to solve a question, for free, for *you*. Even though the question wasn't completely answered, it seems like kind of a dick move to downvote them so that they don't receive the bounty.